# Summary Count by Group with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, activerecord, count

I have a Rails application that holds user data (in an aptly named user_data object). I want to display a summary table that shows me the count of total users and the count of users who are still active (status = 'Active'), created each month for the past 12 months.

In SQL against my Postgres database, I can get the result I want with the following query (the date I use in there is calculated by the application, so you can ignore that aspect):

```
SELECT total.creation_month, 
       total.user_count AS total_count, 
       active.user_count AS active_count
FROM
(SELECT date_trunc('month',"creationDate") AS creation_month, 
        COUNT("userId") AS user_count
  FROM user_data 
  WHERE "creationDate" >= to_date('2015 12 21', 'YYYY MM DD')
  GROUP BY creation_month) AS total
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT date_trunc('month',"creationDate") AS creation_month, 
        COUNT("userId") AS user_count
  FROM user_data 
  WHERE "creationDate" >= to_date('2015 12 21', 'YYYY MM DD')
    AND status = 'Active'
  GROUP BY creation_month) AS active
ON total.creation_month = active.creation_month
ORDER BY creation_month ASC
```

How do I write this query with ActiveRecord?

I previously had just the total user count grouped by month in my display, but I am struggling with how to add in the additional column of active user counts.

My application is on Ruby 2.1.4 and Rails 4.1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on trying to do this the ActiveRecord way. Instead I just constructed my query into a string and passed the string into

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_string)
```

This had the side effect that my result set came out as a array instead of a set of objects. So getting at the values went from a syntax (where user_data is the name assigned to a single record from the result set) like

```
user_data.total_count
```

to

```
user_data['total_count']
```

But that's a minor issue. Not worth the hassle.